# Upper Bound of a Function of a Random Variable(s)?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, upper-lower-bounds

Let $x_l$ be draws from a uniformly distributed random variable $X\in [0,1]$ for the function:
$$f(X) = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{l=1}^n \left[\frac{1}{2}(|x_l - \frac{1}{2}| - |1 - x_l|)\right]$$
where $n$ is some positive integer. I would like to find an upper bound to the above equation. My first thought was to  apply the Markov Inequality, stated as follows:
*if $X$ is any nonnegative random variable, then*
$$P(X \geq a) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(X)}{a}$$
Now, $x_l$ is a nonnegative r.v. but $f(\mathbf{x})$ is not (i.e: simple example if all $x_l$ happen to equal $0$) so would I approach this?

Both Markov's and Chebyshev's inequalities reference random variables *not* functions of random variables so I may also be off base in their applicability as well.

Comment: No precision about the pdf of the $x_i$ ?

Comment: There is an issue about your notation $f(x)$. IMHO, you should write $X_n = ... $ (with an index $n$) instead of $f(x) =...$ because we don't know how $x$ is defined....

Comment: Are you sure the term inside the summation is right? $|1 - x_l|$ is rather redundant, as the argument is alwais non-negative.

Comment: @JeanMarie The notation is likely incorrect. My intention is the following: $x_l$ are random draws from a 1-dimensional (in this case) random variable $X$. We can assume $X$ is uniformly distributed for simplicity

Comment: @leonbloy $|1 - x_l|$ is an intentionally chosen 'draw' ie: assuming the original equation was $|x_k - x_l|$ I am fixing $x_k = 1$

Answer (score 1):

Uhm.. I don't know if this is what you're looking for because the question is very broad, but a possible bound is the following:

since $|1-x_l| \ge 0$ and since $|x_l - \frac{1}{2}| \le 1/2$,  $\forall x_l \in [0,1]$ we have

$$
\begin{align*}
f(x) \le \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{l=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2} \bigg| x_l - \frac{1}{2} \bigg|  \le \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{l=1}^{n} \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{4n}
\end{align*}
$$